# How to construct a triangle with divergently parallel perpendicular bisectors?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm pretty sure it is possible to construct a triangle in the Klein model of hyperbolic geometry such that the perpendicular bisectors are divergently parallel, but I'm struggling to do so. I've been trying to do the problem just by drawing it out and not wanting to calculate distances or anything. Any advice on how I would want to choose the lines that construct my triangle inside the circle?

Comment: Just returned to the problem and it looks good. It took a bit of work to draw the segments such that it fit the description (equidistant) because the scales are off in the model, but I worked with reflecting points so it worked out correctly. Sorry about the source, that's not where the problem was from but something I found after posting the question researching it, but yes I should have once I found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction you want is easy.  In your belatedly cited source, see figure 3.1.  $AB$ is divergently parallel to $CD$.  Construct a short segment perpendicularly bisected by $AB$ (easiest near $A$) that intersects a short segment perpendicularly bisected by $CD$.  The add the third segment.  (Note that both short segments must lie entirely in the circle (except possibly for one point on the circle).)

Edit:  Deleted correct but irrelevant claim about altitudes due to mentally transposing "perpendicular bisector" and "altitude".

Comment: This website says it is possible, but does not explain its construction in the Klein Model which is why I still don't know how to proceed. http://library.umaine.edu/theses/pdf/RossSW2000.pdf It's Theorem 2.32

Comment: @user138011:  Question 1:  Why did you not provide the reference to the article you are reading in your question?

Comment: D'oh.  Transposed "perpendicular bisector" and "altitude".  Editing...

Comment: @user138011:  Are you able to perform your construction now?